# How to store Indian date and Time in MongoDB ? and How to query using Time fileds(HH:MM:SS)

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

What is the best way to store indian date and time in mongodb?
I'm going to upload bill details in mongodb. So i've to capture the Bill time which is printed in Bill. This will be in the format like '2014-12-22 14:10:25'. ISODate is good solution? How to covert above date value into ISODate format? Is there any default fuction avilable in mongodb?

How to query the documents based on time elements.For example hourly wise document search.
Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is possible through JavaScript's Date objec, that supports the ISO date format, so as long as you have access to the date string, you can do something like this:

```
> doo = new Date("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00")
Sat, 14 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT
> doo.toTimeString()
'17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)'
```

If you want the time string without the seconds and the time zone then you can call the getHours() and getMinutes() methods on the Date object and format the time yourself.

if any problem please comment me..)

Comment: Hi I've to store only date and time fileds. The date format would be in bill like  "2014-12-23 12:50:23" . So I've to capture this filed in mongodb for indian standart time.

Comment: then you use the myDate.format("mm/dd/yy"); in that case mydate is your bill date